# Connecting to an Android device remotely

Tags: android, remote-access

I'm trying to build an application that controls the following functionality of an android device using another android device: 
1. Get the current location using GPS 
2. Taking a picture/video using the camera 
3. Viewing photos on the remote device 
4. Watching the messages (SMS) 
5. Turning on the audio recorder

I wanted to get an advice on how to create a connection between the 2 devices (client and agent)?
Thanks in advance, 
Nir

Comment: What you want ("application that controls the basic functionality of an android device using another android device") is not possible without modifications to the OS itself. I would worry about that first, then worry about "how to create a connection between the 2 devices".

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what are the modifications that needs to be done?
Are you talking about rooting the device?
Can you please direct me to how-to general guides that might help me get passed the "O.S modifications"

Comment: "Can you please elaborate on what are the modifications that needs to be done?" -- standard Android apps have no means of sending user input or capturing screens from other apps. "Are you talking about rooting the device?" -- that and more. The people behind VNC have it working with changes to the actual source code of the OS, last I checked.

Comment: OK, I will clarify then - I do not wish to remote control the way VNC does (screen control), but simply key features in the phone.
e.g - Camera, text messaging, file navigation etc.. 

To my understanding this doesn't require O.S modifications, but before I start doing anything, I would like to know it's possible and achievable.

Comment: "but simply key features in the phone" -- we have no way to know what you mean by this, and therefore cannot tell you whether or not it requires OS modifications. For example, "file navigation" implies remote control of a UI, yet you also claim that you are not looking for remote control of a UI. Please click the "edit" link under your question and add several hundred more words explaining completely and precisely what you mean by "controls the basic functionality of an android device".